# How to show content of collection to other users?

Tags: javascript, meteor

At first I am a beginner in meteor. I am creating an app for school. Users can add something to a collection. My problem is that only the author sees the task at the moment. How can i fix it?

Edit: My js code

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) 
    {
    Template.Collection.onCreated(function() {
        var self = this;
        self.autorun(function() {
            self.subscribe('tasks');
        });
    });

    Template.Collection.helpers({
        tasks: ()=> {
            return tasks.find({inCollection: true});
        }
    });

    Template.Tasks.onCreated(function() {
        var self = this;
        self.autorun(function() {
            self.subscribe('tasks');
        });
    });

    Template.tasks.helpers({
        tasks: ()=> {
            return tasks.find({});    
        }
    });

    Template.Tasks.events({
        'click .new-task': () => {
            Session.set('newTask', true);
        }
    });

    Template.TaskSingle.onCreated(function() {
        var self = this;
        self.autorun(function() {
            var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
            self.subscribe('singleTask', id);
        });
    });

    Template.TaskSingle.helpers({
        task: ()=> {
            var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
            return Tasks.findOne({_id: id});
        }
    });

    Template.NewTask.events({
        'click .fa-close' : function() {
            Session.set('newTask', false);
        }
    });

    Template.Task.onCreated(function(){
       this.editMode = new ReactiveVar(false);
       // this.editMode = new ReactiveVar();
       //this.editMode.set(false);
    });

    Template.Task.helpers({
        updateTaskId: function() {
            return this._id;
        },
        editMode: function() {
            return Template.instance().editMode.get();
        }
    });

    Template.Task.events({
        'click .toggle-menu': function() {
            Meteor.call('toggleMenuItem', this._id, this.inCollection);
        },
        'click .fa-trash' : function() {
            Meteor.call('deleteTask', this._id);
        },
        'click .fa-pencil' : function(event, template) {
           template.editMode.set(!template.editMode.get());
        }
    });


    }



    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        Meteor.startup(function () {
            //code to run on server at startup      
    });


    Meteor.publish('tasks', function(){
        return tasks.find({author: this.userId});
    });


    Meteor.publish('singleTask', function(id){
        check(id, String);
        return Tasks.find({_id: id});
    });

    // Configure Accounts to require username instead of email
    Accounts.ui.config({
        passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
    });

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us some code what you have so done far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've removed the `autopublish` package then documents then you need to create publications and subscriptions for documents to be sent to clients.

On the server you write: `Meteor.publish('items', function () { return Items.find(); }`.
And on the client you would subscribe with `Meteor.subscribe('items');`.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly publish the tasks for the author only:

```
Meteor.publish('tasks', function(){
    return Tasks.find({author: this.userId});
});
```

If you want it to be visible to everyone, it should be

```
Meteor.publish('tasks', function(){
    return Tasks.find();
});
```